# Removing specific models

Tags: modeling

[image]I downloaded a Vader model and it comes with the whole body and two guns. I don't wont the guns I want to delete them, but when I try to they delete the head with it. How do I delete the guns without deleting the head?

There is the picture of the model if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gun and head mesh are in one object.

Press the Tab key to enter edit mode, select one of the vertices of the gun, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to select all of the gun's meshes and erase them.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> is the function to select all connected to the currently selected element (vertex, edge, face).

Finally, you will only get the head.

If you want to separate the guns into different objects without erasing them, select the mesh and press the <kbd>P</kbd> key.